# что будет, если удалить папку .git

Tags: git, gitlab

Что делать в случаях, когда нужно подключить свой git, но на сайте уже есть папка .git , но это какая-то старая левая папка, которая осталась ещё от других разрабов или типо того https://disk.yandex.ru/i/sQlIOuFidguDbQ .
Если её просто удалить, то сайт останется просто в том состоянии и на той ветке на которой он там сейчас или нельзя просто так взять и удалить папку .git?

Comment: "сайт останется просто в том состоянии и на той ветке на которой он там сейчас" --- да

Comment: "или нельзя просто так взять и удалить папку .git" --- можно, это просто папка с данными..... можно забэкапить, если хочется

Answer (score 1):

Папка .git хранит в себе необходимую информацию о git репозитория проекта. Проще говоря, удалив эту папку нельзя будет взаимодействовать с тем репозиторием и, например, контролировать его версию. **На нынешний проект удаление никак не повлияет**